# sqlzoo window lag problem #8 getting wrong dates but correct peak cases

Tags: mysql

**NOTE** : *I have cut some of the letters from the names for proper formatting else I would've had to go through each line and do it manually. I cant figure out Why am I getting the wrong dates but the right Peak new covid cases for country.*

Link to the problem: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Window_LAG
Problem #8

**Here's my thought process.**

In this query we have to get the peak new cases for countries where at least 1000 new cases have been  reported in a single day. In this case the confirmed column`(here,confirmed is equal to new cases reported in a day plus the preceding day's cases)` is arranged in cumulative manner. So to get new cases for each day I have made a subquery and within that query I PARTITIONED it by name and ORDERED it by confirmed`(new cases,cumulative)` from least to most and then subtracted the preceding row in the current partition. Which would then give me the table in pure new cases per day form. After that in the main query i have GROUPED the table by name(here,name is country) and then selected the groups with at least 1000 cases reported and finally ordered it by date as seen in the expected result.

Dont know where i went wrong. Everything seems like it should work.

My Query.

```
SELECT name, date, MAX(current_cases) FROM (
    SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(whn,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date, 
    (confirmed - LAG(confirmed,1) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY confirmed) ) AS current_cases
    FROM covid 
) covid2
WHERE covid2.current_cases >= 1000
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY date
```

Expected

```
name    DATE_FORMAT(w.. peakNewCases
China   2020-02-13  15136
Italy   2020-03-21  6557
Switzer 2020-03-23  1321
Spain   2020-03-25  9630
Israel  2020-03-25  1131
Austria 2020-03-26  1321
Germany 2020-03-27  6933
Iran    2020-03-30  3186
Canada  2020-04-05  2778
Ecuador 2020-04-10  2196
Netherl 2020-04-10  1346
Portug  2020-04-10  1516
United  2020-04-10  33755
Ireland 2020-04-10  1515
United  2020-04-10  8733
Turkey  2020-04-11  5138
France  2020-04-12  26849
Peru    2020-04-13  2265
Belgium 2020-04-15  2454
Brazil  2020-04-17  3257
Japan   2020-04-17  1161
Saudi A 2020-04-18  1132
India   2020-04-19  1893
Russia  2020-04-19  6060
Singapo 2020-04-20  1426
Belarus 2020-04-20  1485
```

Got

```
name    date    MAX(current_c..
China   2020-01-28  15136
Iran    2020-03-06  3186
Italy   2020-03-07  6557
France  2020-03-13  26849
Germany 2020-03-13  6933
Spain   2020-03-13  9630
United  2020-03-16  33755
Switzer 2020-03-19  1321
United  2020-03-20  8733
Israel  2020-03-25  1131
Austria 2020-03-26  1321
Belgium 2020-03-26  2454
Netherl 2020-03-26  1346
Turkey  2020-03-26  5138
Canada  2020-03-30  2778
Brazil  2020-03-31  3257
Portuga 2020-03-31  1516
India   2020-04-06  1893
Russia  2020-04-07  6060
Peru    2020-04-08  2265
Ecuador 2020-04-10  2196
Ireland 2020-04-10  1515
Japan   2020-04-17  1161
Saudi A 2020-04-18  1132
Belarus 2020-04-20  1485
Singapo 2020-04-20  1426
```

Hope I gave all the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, that seems to give right dates and peaks, but result order doesn't correspond to one given in the answer on SQLZoo:

```
SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(whn,'%Y-%m-%d') as Date, Peak
FROM (SELECT name, whn,
    confirmed-LAG(confirmed,1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY whn) as newCases, 
    Peak 
    FROM covid
    INNER JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(newCases) as Peak FROM
        (SELECT name, 
            confirmed-LAG(confirmed,1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY whn) as newCases
            FROM covid) AS T1
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING Peak >=1000) AS T2
    USING(name)
ORDER BY whn) AS M
WHERE newCases = Peak
```

Since I was not able to figure out the sort logic in the answer or in the task, I think this solution is correct.